# Saxon rpm build fails due to "ant: command not found"

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

Hopefully this is a question I can ask this community. I'm currently working on building zookeeper-3.4.5-13 for a CentOS 5 environment. During this process I've been going down a long list of required packages ( mockito -> objenesis -> maven -> maven2 -> classworlds -> dom4j -> jtidy-> ant -> jakarata-common-net -> saxon ) and I'm running into an issue building saxon-6.5.5-3.3.

When I build, I get to the %build section of the process and end up erring out with the following:

```
DEBUG: + exit 0
DEBUG: Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mUxwgM
DEBUG: + umask 022
DEBUG: + cd /builddir/build/BUILD
DEBUG: + cd saxon-6.5.5
DEBUG: + LANG=C
DEBUG: + export LANG
DEBUG: + unset DISPLAY
DEBUG: + export CLASSPATH=
DEBUG: + CLASSPATH=
DEBUG: + ant -Dj2se.javadoc=/usr/share/javadoc/java -Djdom.javadoc=/usr/share/javadoc/jdom
DEBUG: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mUxwgM: line 32: ant: command not found
DEBUG: error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mUxwgM (%build)
DEBUG: RPM build errors:
DEBUG:     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mUxwgM (%build)
DEBUG: Child returncode was: 1
```

The first to check is that ant was installed, and sure enough, it was:

```
DEBUG: ================================================================================
DEBUG:  Package                      Arch     Version                     Repository
DEBUG:                                                                            Size
DEBUG: ================================================================================
DEBUG: Installing:
DEBUG:  ant                          i386     1.6.5-2jpp.2                core   2.0 M
DEBUG:  java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc   i386     1:1.6.0.0-1.21.b17.el5      core    20 M
DEBUG:  jdom                         i386     1.0-4jpp.1                  core   328 k
DEBUG:  jdom-javadoc                 i386     1.0-4jpp.1                  core   305 k
DEBUG:  jpackage-utils               noarch   1.7.5-3.8.iot5              core    63 k
DEBUG:  xml-commons-apis
```

Any other information I can provide as needed, but if anyone could tell me why ant isn't found it would be appreciated.

For more insight, this is being done with mock and going into the mock shell does show that any is missing from any locations that would be considered normal to run from.

Answer (score 1):

The ant executable cannot be found in your path.

Run
     rpm -ql ant | grep 'bin/ant$'
and make sure that the bin/ directory is included in your
PATH variable.